# Commutativity of multiplication for natural numbers (Terence Tao's Analysis I exercise 3.6.5)

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise 3.6.5: Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Show that $A\times B$ and $B\times A$ have equal cardinality by construction an explicit bijection between the two sets. Then use Proposition 3.6.14 (the one about the cardinal arithmetic) to conclude an alternative proof of Lemma 2.3.2 (this lemma proves the commutativity of multiplication).

The bijection is quite easy. But I've no idea why is he asking me to prove a property of multiplication with the cardinality of cartesian products. He defined the natural numbers and its operations with the Peano axioms, no with cardinality, so Tao hasn't really provided a construction of the naturals using only set theory.

What's the point of the exercise? Am I supposed to provide this construction, define the multiplication operation and then prove it or am I missing something?

Comment: "defined the natural numbers and its operations with the P axioms, no with card"  No, but he defined the cardinality of finite sets with natural numbers, didn't he?  A set $A$ is finite if there is a natural number $k$ so that a bijection between $\{0,1,.....,k-1\}$ and $A$ exist.  Then he probably demonstrated that if such was the case, that $k$ was unique and that $|A| =k$ is well defined way of associating finite sets with a uniq nat number.  Prop 3.6.14 tells us if $A$ and $B$ are finit $A\times B$ is finite and that $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot|B|$. That *IS* a statement about natural numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the hint you're given for 3.6.14, I see:

> (e) Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Then Cartesian product $X \times Y$ is finite and $\#(X \times Y ) = \#(X) \times \#(Y )$.

So if you have sets $A,B$ with $|A|=n$ and $|B|=m$, $|A\times B|=n\times m$.

Using exercise 3.6.5, one would also see $|A\times B|=|B\times A|=m\times n$, proving $n\times m = m\times n$ in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It does not says that. It actually only says that cardinal arithmetic is an alternative foundation than Peano's but that he won't develop it. He gives no definition of any operation or of N for that matter other than Peano's. So I'm left wondering if he expects me to define those things for myself for the exercise. If I assume the definition you gave then it'd be easy. But I've no idea what he expects from me hehe. Well, thanks anyway!

Comment: @bibliotecatlon Uh, Proposition 3.6.14 (e) says precisely what you claim he does not say.  It appears in your hint...  Maybe take a break and get a coffee.

Comment: Thanks rschwieb. That proposition does not define the operation of multiplication in the naturals explicitly, so I was unsure if I could just use it directly without a definition of naturals and their operations using cardinal numbers. I'm self-studying so I may be too careful/unsure. Well, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @bibliotecatlon Why would he have to redefine the operation of multiplication in the naturals explicitly for that proposition? Seems like he would want to stick to the established one.